# Calculate time difference for attendance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, sql-server-2005

I have a table with the below sample output.

```
UserID  Checktime              CheckStatus
3175    2013-12-22 07:02:10.000     I
3175    2013-12-22 13:01:01.000     O
3175    2013-12-22 13:49:54.000     I
3175    2013-12-22 13:49:55.000     I
3175    2013-12-22 15:58:42.000     O
3175    2013-12-23 06:02:58.000     I
3175    2013-12-23 14:00:29.000     O
3175    2013-12-24 05:17:09.000     I
3175    2013-12-24 12:34:25.000     O
3175    2013-12-24 12:34:26.000     O
```

I want to build a query to achieve the below results:

```
UserID  Date       CheckIn   CheckOut Hours
3175    2013-12-22 07:02:10  13:01:0  5.98
3175    2013-12-22 13:49:54  15:58:42 2.15
```

Notice:
1. The duplicate IN is ignored.Third and fourth lines in the raw data.
2. Minutes are in decimal point to the hour in the hours calculation.

I need help of the tsql query to use to get these results.

My current code is causing lots of other issues - because it has to be recalculated in temporary tables everytime.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server you using?

Comment: Mike thanks for your reply - am using sql server 2005

Comment: What do you want to happen if the in/out overlaps a day boundary?  Obviously the out-time won't have the same date (so your result checkin/checkout columns may need a date portion).  What about situations with only a checkout time?  Only a checkin time?  When there are duplicate checkouts?

Answer (score 6):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
    UserID INT,
    Checktime DATETIME,
    CheckStatus CHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (UserID, Checktime, CheckStatus)
VALUES 
    (3175, '20131222 07:02:10.000', 'I'),
    (3175, '20131222 13:01:01.000', 'O'),
    (3175, '20131222 13:49:54.000', 'I'),
    (3175, '20131222 13:49:55.000', 'I'),
    (3175, '20131222 15:58:42.000', 'O'),
    (3175, '20131223 06:02:58.000', 'I'),
    (3175, '20131223 14:00:29.000', 'O'),
    (3175, '20131224 05:17:09.000', 'I'),
    (3175, '20131224 12:34:25.000', 'O'),
    (3175, '20131224 12:34:26.000', 'O')

SELECT 
      t.UserID
    , [Date] = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, t.CheckIn))
    , CheckIn = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t.CheckIn, 108)
    , CheckOut = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t.CheckOut, 108)
    , [Hours] = CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t.CheckIn, t.CheckOut) / 60. AS DECIMAL(10,2))
FROM (
    SELECT 
          t.UserID
        , CheckIn = t.Checktime
        , CheckOut = r.Checktime
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.UserID, r.Checktime ORDER BY 1/0)
    FROM @temp t
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM @temp t2
        WHERE t2.UserID = t.UserID
            AND t2.Checktime > t.Checktime
            AND DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, t.Checktime)) = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, t2.Checktime))
            AND t2.CheckStatus = 'O'
        ORDER BY t2.Checktime
    ) r
    WHERE t.CheckStatus = 'I'
) t
WHERE t.RowNum = 1
```

Output -

```
UserID      Date                    CheckIn    CheckOut   Hours
----------- ----------------------- ---------- ---------- --------
3175        2013-12-22 00:00:00.000 07:02:10   13:01:01   5.98
3175        2013-12-22 00:00:00.000 13:49:54   15:58:42   2.15
3175        2013-12-23 00:00:00.000 06:02:58   14:00:29   7.97
3175        2013-12-24 00:00:00.000 05:17:09   12:34:25   7.28
```

Comment: do we need to distinct records? can you please explain above code.

Comment: Does the CROSS APPLY subquery need ordering here? It might not be guarateed to be in the correct order in the table.

Comment: Devart>Thanks for your fast reply. The code works but has  unrealistic results when an employee Checks IN and forgets to Check Out. What the code does is take the first IN and the next OUT ignoring if there was another IN the following day.

Comment: UserID  Checktime              CheckStatus (sample data)
3175 2013-04-02 10:10:16.000   I
3175 2013-04-02 10:10:20.000   I
3175 2013-04-03 06:28:07.000   I
3175 2013-04-03 13:01:33.000   O
3175 2013-04-03 14:04:22.000   I
3175 2013-04-03 16:02:23.000   O
3175 2013-04-04 06:24:02.000   I

Comment: Ok. Please see the updated answer `CROSS` -> `OUTER`

Comment: How many rows contained in your table? `CROSS/OUTER APPLY` - very time-consuming operation.

Comment: @Devart>I have 702,528 rows in that table. The results this time are more accurate looking at a glance. Will study the data and give a proper response on that. Is there a way to improve performamnce?

Comment: I can confirm the results are indeed accurate and is what I wanted. My challenge with the query is that it is very slow.

Comment: Please provide a execution plan for this query.

Comment: I guess this doesn't need to be ran live? populate another reporting table and then batch populate overnight.  Just my two cents.  The query is good but for that size dataset I think you'll struggle to get it quick enough.

Answer (score 0):

I took Devart's code and improved it. What I do is I use OUTER APPLY to grab the next row for each "IN" status. I then sort out the bad rows in the where clause.  If there are two "IN" in a row, then it grabs the later one.

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
    UserID INT,
    Checktime DATETIME,
    CheckStatus CHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (UserID, Checktime, CheckStatus)
VALUES 
    (3175, '20131222 07:02:10.000', 'I'),
    (3175, '20131222 13:01:01.000', 'O'),
    (3175, '20131222 13:49:54.000', 'I'),
    (3175, '20131222 13:49:55.000', 'I'),
    (3175, '20131222 15:58:42.000', 'O'),
    (3175, '20131223 06:02:58.000', 'I'),
    (3175, '20131223 14:00:29.000', 'O'),
    (3175, '20131224 05:17:09.000', 'I'),
    (3175, '20131224 12:34:25.000', 'O'),
    (3175, '20131224 12:34:26.000', 'O')

SELECT  UserID,
        CAST(I.CheckTime AS DATE) AS [Date],
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), I.CheckTime, 108) AS CheckIn,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), O.CheckTime, 108) AS CheckOut,
        CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,I.checkTime,O.CheckTime)/60.0 AS DECIMAL(18,2)) [Hours]
FROM @temp I
OUTER APPLY (
                SELECT TOP 1    Checktime,
                                CheckStatus
                FROM @temp t
                WHERE       t.UserID = I.UserID
                        AND t.Checktime > I.Checktime
                ORDER BY t.Checktime
            ) O
WHERE I.CheckStatus = 'I'
AND O.CheckStatus = 'O'
```

Results:

```
UserID      Date       CheckIn    CheckOut   Hours
----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -----
3175        2013-12-22 07:02:10   13:01:01   5.98
3175        2013-12-22 13:49:55   15:58:42   2.15
3175        2013-12-23 06:02:58   14:00:29   7.97
3175        2013-12-24 05:17:09   12:34:25   7.28
```

Answer (score 0):

Can this insert into be able to change with SELECT Query?

```
INSERT INTO @temp (UserID, Checktime, CheckStatus)
VALUES 
    (3175, '20131222 07:02:10.000', 'I'),
    (3175, '20131222 13:01:01.000', 'O'),
    (3175, '20131222 13:49:54.000', 'I'),
    (3175, '20131222 13:49:55.000', 'I'),
    (3175, '20131222 15:58:42.000', 'O'),
    (3175, '20131223 06:02:58.000', 'I'),
    (3175, '20131223 14:00:29.000', 'O'),
    (3175, '20131224 05:17:09.000', 'I'),
    (3175, '20131224 12:34:25.000', 'O'),
    (3175, '20131224 12:34:26.000', 'O')
```