# Employee Monthly Attendance Using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, one is `Tab_Users` containing user details and the other is `Tab_CardEntry` containing their card entries. I need to get their minimum and maximum card entry time for each user on a daily basis.

Here is the SQL query I used

```
SELECT
    A.Name,
    ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR, MIN(B.DATED), 108), 'OFF') LOGEDIN,
    ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR, MAX(B.DATED), 108), 'OFF') LOGEDOUT
FROM TAB_USERS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
        USERNAME,
        DATED
    FROM TAB_CARDENTRY
    WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATED, 106) = CONVERT(VARCHAR, '02 Jan 2014', 106)
) B ON A.USERNAME = B.USERNAME
GROUP BY A.Name
ORDER BY 1
```

I need this type of output

[image]

Comment: This is a duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882934/calculate-time-difference-for-attendance#20883190.

Comment: @Jaques No it is not. I need it for complete month not for a single day.

Comment: You could create a new table which contains one record per day - and populate it with a few years.  Then INNER JOIN this new table with the CardEntry and you could GROUP BY the day.  You will need to play around to get exactly what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Stored Proc that you can try

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetTimes @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    --Make sure that only 31 days of data is used otherwise the temp table will be too big
    IF @EndDate IS NULL OR DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) > 31
      SET @EndDate = DATEADD(dd, 31, @StartDate)

    SELECT UserID, CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, DateTimeIn))) ForDate, DateTimeIn, DateTimeOut
    INTO #Times
    FROM
    (
    SELECT  DISTINCT MIN(a.DATED) OVER (PARTITION BY a.USERNAME, CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, DATED)))) DateTimeIn,
            MAX(a.DATED) OVER (PARTITION BY a.USERNAME, CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, DATED)))) DateTimeOut, 
            USERNAME AS UserID
    FROM TAB_CARDENTRY a
    WHERE DATED BETWEEN @StartDate and @EndDate + 1
    ) a

    SELECT DISTINCT ForDate INTO #Dates FROM #Times

    --Select * from #Times order by 1
    --Select * from #Dates

    DECLARE @SQLstring VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @SQLstring = 'CREATE TABLE ##Test (UserID varchar(10), '

    DECLARE @ForDate DATETIME

    WHILE 0 < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Dates)
        BEGIN
        SET ROWCOUNT 1
        SELECT @ForDate = ForDate FROM #Dates order by ForDate
        SET ROWCOUNT 0
        SET @SQLstring = @SQLstring + '[Entry ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @ForDate, 106) + '] datetime, [Exit ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @ForDate, 106) + '] datetime,' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
        DELETE #Dates WHERE ForDate = @ForDate
        END

    SET @SQLstring = SUBSTRING(@SQLSTRING, 1, LEN(@SQLSTRING) - 3) + ')'
    EXEC (@SQLstring)
    CREATE INDEX idx1 on ##Test(UserID)

    DECLARE @UserID VARCHAR(10),
            @DateIn DATETIME,
            @DateOut DATETIME

    WHILE 0 < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Times)
        BEGIN
        SET ROWCOUNT 1
        SELECT @UserID = UserID, @DateIn = DateTimeIn, @DateOut = DateTimeOut, @ForDate = ForDate from #Times
        SET ROWCOUNT 0
        SET @SQLString = 'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ##Test WHERE UserID = ''' + @UserID + ''')' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
                         '  INSERT ##Test (UserID, [Entry ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @ForDate, 106) + '], [Exit ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @ForDate, 106) + ']) ' +
                         '      SELECT ''' + @UserID + ''', ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @DateIn, 113) + ''', ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @DateOut, 113) + '''' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
                         'ELSE' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
                         '  UPDATE ##Test SET [Entry ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @ForDate, 106) + '] = ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @DateIn, 113) + ''', ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
                         '  [Exit ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @ForDate, 106) + '] = ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @DateOut, 113) + ''' WHERE UserID = ''' + @UserID + ''''
        EXEC (@SQLstring)
        DELETE #Times WHERE UserID = @UserID AND ForDate = @ForDate
        END

    SELECT * FROM ##Test ORDER BY 1
    DROP TABLE ##Test
END
```

**EDIT**

I've looked at the query again and you might not like the output, so you can change a part of the SP to look like this:

The part that creates the temp table

```
WHILE 0 < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Dates)
            BEGIN
            SET ROWCOUNT 1
            SELECT @ForDate = ForDate FROM #Dates order by ForDate
            SET ROWCOUNT 0
            SET @SQLstring = @SQLstring + '[Entry ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @ForDate, 106) + '] varchar(20), [Exit ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @ForDate, 106) + '] varchar(20),' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
            DELETE #Dates WHERE ForDate = @ForDate
            END
```

And the part that inserts the data into the table

```
WHILE 0 < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Times)
    BEGIN
    SET ROWCOUNT 1
    SELECT @UserID = UserID, @DateIn = DateTimeIn, @DateOut = DateTimeOut, @ForDate = ForDate from #Times
    SET ROWCOUNT 0
    SET @SQLString = 'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ##Test WHERE UserID = ''' + @UserID + ''')' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
                     '  INSERT ##Test (UserID, [Entry ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @ForDate, 106) + '], [Exit ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @ForDate, 106) + ']) ' +
                     '      SELECT ''' + @UserID + ''', ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), ISNULL(@DateIn, '''OFF''', 108) + ''', ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), ISNULL(@DateOut, '''OFF'''), 108) + '''' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
                     'ELSE' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
                     '  UPDATE ##Test SET [Entry ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @ForDate, 106) + '] = ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), ISNULL(@DateIn, '''OFF'''), 108) + ''', ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
                     '  [Exit ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @ForDate, 106) + '] = ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), ISNULL(@DateOut, '''OFF''', 108) + ''' WHERE UserID = ''' + @UserID + ''''
    EXEC (@SQLstring)
    DELETE #Times WHERE UserID = @UserID AND ForDate = @ForDate
    END
```

Comment: Thanks.but getting Error 
usp_GetTimes '1-dec-2013','31-dec-2013' Msg 2715, Level 16, State 7, Line 1
Column, parameter, or variable #2: Cannot find data type time.

Comment: I thought you were using SQL 2012. Make it datetime, and it should work.