# Get Min In time and Max out TIme. Fom Attendance record in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working on attendance system, and below is my data in sql server database

```
|EmpCode|Date       |WorkDate   |CheckIn    |CheckOut   |TotalTime
|143    |2017-02-13 |2017-02-13 |20:09:02   |22:38:50   |2.496666000
|143    |2017-02-13 |2017-02-13 |22:59:19   |23:18:15   |0.315555000
|143    |2017-02-13 |2017-02-13 |23:33:47   |05:04:24   |5.510277000
|143    |2017-02-14 |2017-02-13 |02:52:38   |05:12:04   |2.323888000
|143    |2017-02-14 |2017-02-14 |20:09:26   |21:59:27   |1.833611000
|143    |2017-02-14 |2017-02-14 |22:30:10   |22:49:26   |0.321111000
|143    |2017-02-15 |2017-02-14 |05:05:05   |05:08:13   |0.052222000
```

-- I want the output like

```
|EmpCode|wrk        |InTime     |OutTime    |TotalTime
|143    |2017-02-13 |08:09:02 PM|05:12:04 AM|10:38:00
|143    |2017-02-14 |08:09:26 PM|05:08:13 AM|02:12:00
```

Comment: SQLzim had a good answer.  they just needed to concat the date for checkin and checkout times

Comment: How did you get those totals? Are you using symbolic values?

Comment: sum total time. you get 10.646 or there abouts.  10 is hours.  take .646 * 60 and you get 38 roughly.

Comment: I took the reference of total time from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882934/calculate-time-difference-for-attendance

Comment: which version are you using... you tagged 4... remove the tags that don't fit your version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want those specific formats for times:

rextester: http://rextester.com/FUW31296

```
create table t (
     EmpCode int
  ,  Date datetime
  ,  WorkDate datetime
  ,  CheckIn datetime
  ,  CheckOut datetime
  ,  TotalTime decimal(19, 9))

insert into t values
 (143,'2017-02-13','2017-02-13','20:09:02','22:38:50',2.496666000)
,(143,'2017-02-13','2017-02-13','22:59:19','23:18:15',0.315555000)
,(143,'2017-02-13','2017-02-13','23:33:47','05:04:24',5.510277000)
,(143,'2017-02-14','2017-02-13','02:52:38','05:12:04',2.323888000)
,(143,'2017-02-14','2017-02-14','20:09:26','21:59:27',1.833611000)
,(143,'2017-02-14','2017-02-14','22:30:10','22:49:26',0.321111000)
,(143,'2017-02-15','2017-02-14','05:05:05','05:08:13',0.052222000);
```

query:

```
select 
     EmpCode
  ,  wrk       = convert(varchar(10),WorkDate,120)
  ,  InTime    = format(cast(min(Date + CheckIn) as datetime), 'hh:mm:ss tt')
  ,  OutTime   = format(cast(max(Date + CheckOut) as datetime), 'hh:mm:ss tt')
  ,  TotalTime = format(dateadd(minute,sum(TotalTime)*60,0), 'HH:mm:ss')
from t
group by 
    EmpCode
  , WorkDate
```

results:

```
+---------+------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
| EmpCode |    wrk     |   InTime    |   OutTime   | TotalTime |
+---------+------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|     143 | 2017-02-13 | 08:09:02 PM | 05:12:04 AM | 10:38:00  |
|     143 | 2017-02-14 | 08:09:26 PM | 05:08:13 AM | 02:12:00  |
+---------+------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Comment: You were definitely on the right path before the deleted answer and the update looks good!

Comment: Thanks. I backed out when I noticed the formats weren't going to be what was specified in the result and wanted to test before restoring.

Comment: @xQbert The post link in your profile has been deleted :(

Comment: Oh well. I'll remove the link.  Thanks.  but i'll keep the gist of the exchange.  I still find it funny.

Comment: @xQbert I agree, Wish I could I have seen it in context.

Answer (score 1):

```
select  *
,       datediff(minute, first_in, last_out) as Totaltime
from    (
        select  emp_reader_id
        ,       min(case when Event_entry.event_entry_name = 'IN' then trnevents.DT end) as Intime
        ,       max(case when Event_entry.event_entry_name = 'OUT' then trnevents.DT end) as Outtime
        ,       cast(min(trnevents.DT) as date) as date
        from    trnevents inner join Event_entry on trnevents.EventCatId=Event_entry.EventCatId
        group by
                emp_reader_id
        ,       cast(trnevents.DT as date)
        ) as SubQueriesMustBeNamed
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select EmpCode, WorkDate as wrk, min(InTime) as InTime, max(OutTime) as OutTime, Sum(TotalTime) as TotalTime
from yourtable
group by EmpCode, WorkDate
```

will give you the smallest `InTime`, the bigest `OutTime` and the total `TotalTime` from `yourtable` per user per day.

Comment: Don't think this handles the 4th line correctly as the "Min" checkin would be 02:52:38  and total time is not in the right format.